# MYSQL Show each date in case when

Tags: mysql, sql

I would like to show each date in a case when query such as

```
SELECT pp.user_id, p.payment_profile_id, 
       Max(case when p.transaction_type='New Order' THEN date(p.created_at) end ) as 'new_order_date',
       (case when p.transaction_type='Renewal Order' THEN date(p.created_at) end) as 'renew_date' 
from payments p
    join payment_profiles pp on pp.id = p.payment_profile_id
```

If I didn't add Max but it shows blank in the last two columns.

```
user.id payment_profile_id new_order_date  renew_date
    1         aaa                  (NULL)    (NULL)
```

If I add Max but it shows blank in the last column.

```
user.id payment_profile_id new_order_date  renew_date
    1         aaa                  1/1/2013     (NULL)
```

And if I remove group by, it will show up multiple rows but not

```
user.id payment_profile_id new_order_date  renew_date
    1         aaa                  1/1/2013     (NULL)
    1         aaa                  (NULL)       (NULL)
    1         aaa                  (NULL)       3/1/2013
    1         aaa                  (NULL)       4/1/2013
```

I would like to get the result like--

```
user.id payment_profile_id new_order_date  renew_date
1         aaa                  1/1/2013     3/1/2013
1         aaa                  1/1/2013     4/1/2013
```

The new order date only needs the latest one but one new order date may have many renew dates.

However, If I use this query, the renew date doesn't show the result..

Comment: can you add some sample data

Comment: GROUP BY missing.

Comment: Please show the records for which you expect the shown result.

Comment: Hi all, I have added some records.. thanks in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
SELECT p.payment_profile_id,p.created_at as Renewal_Date, a.max_new_order_date as Order_Date FROM p left join
(select id,payment_profile_id, transaction_type, max(created_at) as max_new_order_date from p where  transaction_type='New Order' group by payment_profile_id) a on p.payment_profile_id=a.payment_profile_id where p.transaction_type="Renewal Order";
```

The above is to list out max order date that is group by payment_profile_id then later join with the original table so that could list out all individual order date.